# "incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'char'[100]" am I using strcat right?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, fwrite, strcat

Good day,

I am writing a datalogging program for my IMU's. I want to add a newline after every value logged, however, I keep on getting an error on this line:

```
strcat(file_DT,"\n");
```

The error states that there is an "incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'char'[100]"

I tried using

```
file_DT+="\n";
```

earlier but it turns out it only works on strings.

I could not find any solutions to my predicament. Is there a better way to do this? Your help would be very appreciated :)

```
float deltaTime2;
FILE *fileDT;
char file_DT[100];
const char *filenameDT = "dT.txt";

while(1){

    /* do quadcopter orentation sampling here */

// log DT
fileDT = fopen(filenameDT, "a+");
    if (fileDT){ //if file exists
        snprintf(file_DT, 100, "%f", deltaTime2);
        strcat(file_DT,"\n");
        fwrite(&file_DT[0], sizeof(char), 100, fileDT);
        cout << "Logging DT" << << endl;
        fclose(fileDT);
        fileDT = NULL;
    }
    else{ //no file, generate file
        cout << "No file present, generating new fileDT" <<     endl;
        snprintf(file_DT, 100, "%f", deltaTime2);
        strcat(file_DT,"\n");
        fwrite(&file_DT[0], sizeof(char), 100, fileDT);
        fclose(fileDT);
        fileDT = NULL;
    }

}
```

Comment: As a sidenote, naming two variables `file_DT` and `fileDT` is highly confusing.

Comment: I doubt that you're getting that error for that line (there's not a hint of assignment in it). Unrelated to your problem: you don't need `strcat` for this - just `fwrite` a newline after you've written `file_DT`. Even better: use `std::ofstream fileDT` and `fileDT << deltaTime2 << '\n';`

Comment: Or `fprintf(file_DT, "%f\n", deltaTime2);`, if you're determined to write "C in C++".

Comment: What's the point in using `strcat` here? You might as well call `snprintf` with `"%f\n"` instead of `"%f"`. In addition, you are writing a whole bunch of zeros into the file. Why not use `fprintf` in order to write only the actual data? In fact, you may as well do the whole thing with `fprintf` rather than this odd combination of `snprintf`, `strcat` and `fwrite`. If want to make use of C++ benefits, then there are proper built-in (STL) functions for this.

Comment: 1) What does "IMU" mean, anyway? 2) `strcat` cannot be used right because it's never the appropriate solution in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minimal change could be rewrite the following lines

```
    snprintf(file_DT, 100, "%f", deltaTime2);
    strcat(file_DT,"\n");
    fwrite(&file_DT[0], sizeof(char), 100, fileDT);
```

as

```
    int datalen = snprintf(file_DT, 100, "%f\n", deltaTime2);
    fwrite(&file_DT[0], sizeof(char), datalen, fileDT);
```

This way you get the newline and write just the required data.
Otherwise you end up writing garbage to file (your line is likely shorter than 100 bytes)

Comment: The "writing garbage" is actually undefined behaviour (passing uninitialized variables to a library function) , so anything could happen

Answer (score 2):

If I can suggest this kind of code is better do in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namspace std;

const string filenameDT;

int main()
{
    ofstream file(filenameDT);
    file << deltaTime2 << endl;
    cout << "Logging DT" << endl;        
}
```

We're in 2016! Don't write code as that!